# Given the following nonlinear PDE: $\partial_{tt} u(x,t)=ku(x,t)\partial_{xx}u(x,t)$, with $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$, is it possible to solve it analytically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the following nonlinear PDE: $\partial_{tt} u(x,t)=ku(x,t)\partial_{xx}u(x,t)$, with $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$, is it possible to solve it analytically?

Could the solutions have singularities that can be interpreted as shock waves?

Comment: Did you try that way? $$u(x,t)=P(x)T(t)$$ 
$$\partial_{tt} u(x,t)=ku(x,t)\partial_{xx}u(x,t)$$  

$$P(x)T''(t)=kP(x)T(t)P''(x)T(t)$$ 
$$P(x)T''(t)=kP(x)P''(x)T^2(t)$$ 
$$\frac{T''(t)}{T^2(t)}=kP''(x)=c$$ 
c is a constant.